# if B2 matches U:U then return corresponding T:T

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am attempting to find matching numbers and return a revision.. basically brain stuck =)

if B2 matches U:U 
then return corresponding T:T

any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? And where are you stuck? Could you not put that in a formula?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please read [how do I ask a good question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
=INDEX(T:T,MATCH(B2,U:U))
```